# Exit function in C

Tags: c, function, exit

I have this excersice in my university, and we are not allowed to use stdlib. I used exit in some places and for some reason visual studio did not yell at me for not including stdlib. Now I'm compiling on the university servers and obviously it's not working (I did not know exit belongs to stdlib).

The question : How is the exit function defined ?

Comment: A proposal : replace `exit(n);` with `return n;` statement.

Comment: while compiling you can use -w option in the gcc complier. it will remove the warning messages.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can call `exit` without having to include `stdlib.h`: just put the `exit` declaration at the top of your source file:

```
void exit(int status);
```

Now the objective of your exercise is probably to not use any function from `stdlib.h`.

If you aren't prohibited from using `signal.h`, then just call `raise( SIGTERM )` instead of exit.

Comment: Can we do the same with all other functions in a library, just by including the declarations on top? Just curious.

Comment: The professor did not want us to use malloc and such.. it is not about exit. thank you !

Comment: I apologize apparently my makefile/cfile didn't update.

Answer (score 2):

I imagine that the intent is not to call anything from `<stdlib.h>` so hacking around by doing 'extern' is probably not what is desired.

So all you can do is to return a value from `main()` at the appropriate point.

Answer (score 1):

> we are not allowed to use stdlib.

Well, a quick workaround may be, use `#include <unistd.h>` and use [`_exit()` / `_Exit()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/_exit).

Otherwise, you're free to replace `exit()` call with `return` statement, as I mentioned in my comment above.

Comment: @ouah i forgot to add `_Exit()` which requires `c99`. Thanks for pointing out sir.